# Node JS with Cronjob: Screen terminates when detached, but I want to have it run indefinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, cron

I'm using terminal with node.js, and the screen keeps terminating. I'm not sure what is happening, but I would love for the script to run every day, not terminate when I detach.

In terminal, I run: screen node server.js

server.js contains:

```
var cronJob = cron.job('06 17 * * *', function(){
// do things
});
cronJob.start();

//  send Responses
var cronJob2 = cron.job('04 19 * * *', function(){
// do other things
});
cronJob2.start();

var cronJob3 = cron.job('06 19 * * *', function(){
// do other things
});
cronJob3.start();

var cronJob4 = cron.job('05 17 * * *', function(){
// do other things
});
cronJob4.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to `nohup` to detached from terminal as following

```
nohup node server.js > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and you may check running

```
ps aux | grep node
```

I hope this will help you :)